How to debug and handle MIDDLEWARE_INVOCATION_FAILED error on vercel
I built an next.js project which runs locally without an problem.
After deploying it to vercel I'm not able to use the login, which is based on firebase auth.
In the browser console i just receive the "MIDDLEWARE_INVOCATION_FAILED" error.
The vercel documentation offers just a very generally speaking problem guide:
"The MIDDLEWARE_INVOCATION_FAILED error occurs when there is an issue with the Edge Middleware being invoked on the Edge Network. This error can be caused by a variety of issues, including unhandled exceptions."
The logs of the deployment aren't helpful too. They are just telling me "[Error: Failed to determine project ID: TypeError: fetch failed]" for the login request.
The project ID is present and also accessible, i log it after the creation of the firebase app and it's part of the logged firebase app.
This is the middleware:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import {
  authMiddleware,
  redirectToHome,
  redirectToLogin,
} from "next-firebase-auth-edge";
import { clientConfig, serverConfig } from "./config";

const PUBLIC_PATHS = ["/login"];

export async function middleware(request) {
  return authMiddleware(request, {
    loginPath: "/api/login",
    logoutPath: "/api/logout",
    apiKey: clientConfig.apiKey,
    cookieName: serverConfig.cookieName,
    cookieSignatureKeys: serverConfig.cookieSignatureKeys,
    cookieSerializeOptions: serverConfig.cookieSerializeOptions,

    handleValidToken: async ({ token, decodedToken }, headers) => {
      if (PUBLIC_PATHS.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
        console.log("Redirect to Home")
        return redirectToHome(request);
      }

      return NextResponse.next({
        request: {
          headers,
        },
      });
    },
    handleInvalidToken: async (reason) => {
      console.info("Missing or malformed credentials", { reason });

      return redirectToLogin(request, {
        path: "/login",
        publicPaths: PUBLIC_PATHS,
      });
    },
    handleError: async (error) => {
      console.error("Unhandled authentication error", { error });

      return redirectToLogin(request, {
        path: "/login",
        publicPaths: PUBLIC_PATHS,
      });
    },
  });
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/((?!_next|api|.*\\.).*)", "/api/login", "/api/logout"],
};


How can i find where the error occurs or does somebody knows how to fix it?
